# Flash real-time information connection over wifi (lan?)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, communication, wifi, real-time

I would like to create a flash-based app for a tablet that sends messages to a 'receiver' app on the same wifi network. So I can have a bunch of tablets with app A that send info to app B, all on the same network.  What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking into this concept myself recently. I'd type all I've learned in here(maybe soon), but this link can explain it in greater detail than my understanding at this point :

CAUTION - Link is no longer valid.

[http://www.flashrealtime.com/local-flash-peer-to-peer-communication-over-lan-without-cirrus](http://tomkrcha.com/?p=1803)/

Comment: link's out of date, redirects to a site that crashed my computer. don't click it? not sure else what to say here.